# Magento with Custom Helper Function failed to open

Tags: magento, nginx, mage

I did two fresh installations of magento 1.9.0.1, one in my pc with wampserver (apache 2.44, php5.4.12) and the second in my shared hosting with nginx and php5.4.4, both working [b]fine [/b]without errors in log.

I create the simple function with a Helper class to compare the taxvat number p.e.:

app/etc/modules/MyF_checkF.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyF_checkF>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MyF_checkF>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/MyF/checkF/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
     <global>
         <helpers>
            <checkF>
                <class>MyF_checkF_Helper</class>
            </checkF>
        </helpers> 
     </global>
 </config>
```

app/code/local/MyF/checkF/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php

class MyF_checkF_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function validVAT($vat)
    {
        if($vat == 123) 
                    return TRUE;
            else 
                    return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Copied the /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php to the /app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php and added after the taxvat check

```
if ($attribute->getIsRequired() && !Mage::helper('checkF')->validVAT($this->getTaxvat())){
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('TAX/VAT wrong.');
            }
```

In my PC localhost works without errors, log clean, but in the shared hosting I got:

system.log

```
Warning: include(Mage/CheckF/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/clients/client0/web10/web/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/CheckF/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/clients/client0/web10/web/app/code/local:/var/www/clients/client0/web10/web/app/code/community:/var/www/clients/client0/web10/web/app/code/core:/var/www/clients/client0/web10/web/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/clients/client0/web10/web/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

error.log

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_CheckF_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/clients/client0/web10/web/app/Mage.php on line 547" while reading response header from upstream, request: "POST /index.php/customer/account/createpost/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9019"
```

Both installations with magento cache disabled, idk why in shared hosting the magento looks for Mage/CheckF.. instead local/checkf, but in localhost works.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning: include(Mage/CheckF/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream, it is trying to locate in Mage package instead of your custom module MyF, this might give you a clue,

and correct your name , MyF_checkF_Helper_Data to MyF_CheckF_Helper_Data, as Magento autloads classes from directory

Comment: Thanks!! The problem was the uppercase of checkF.

Answer (score 1):

Need change helper `checkF` to `checkf` ...
 and use `Mage::helper('checkF')` instead of `Mage::helper('checkf')`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyF_checkF>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyF_checkF>
    </modules>
     <global>
         <helpers>
            <checkf>
                <class>MyF_checkF_Helper</class>
            </checkf>
        </helpers> 
     </global>
 </config>
```